# R: loop for saving plot in another loop

Tags: r, plot

I am running a R script to create a correlation analysis for data in several monitoring wells. Therefore, I created a loop for every well at one column. In R studio I can view and export the graphs.

I would like to create a solution for saving them automatically. I hope you can help me. Thanks!

In the last row, I was writing down the command to save the file, but I have to create a loop for it. Any ideas how to use the data to create a loop for that?

```
NH3 <- read.table("//laboratory data/Trendanalysis_R/NH3.csv",header=T,sep=",",dec=".")
header<-read.table("//laboratory data/Trendanalysis_R/NH3.csv",header=F, sep=",", dec=".")
header<-header[1,]
Date<-NH3[,1]
Date<-as.Date(Date,"%d/%m/%Y")
library(Hmisc)

for (i in 2:8){
  monitoring_well<-NH3[,i]
  titel<-paste("Trend analysis of", header[,i])
  a=plot(Date,monitoring_well,ylab="Ammonia [mg/l]",main=titel,col.main="darkblue",pch=20,col="darkblue")
  abline(lm(monitoring_well~Date),col="red")
  corr_coeff<-rcorr(Date,monitoring_well,type="spearman")
  df.corr_coeff.r=data.frame(corr_coeff$r)
  df.corr_coeff.P=data.frame(corr_coeff$P)
  corr_P_plot<-df.corr_coeff.P[1,2]
  corr_r_plot<-df.corr_coeff.r[1,2]
  corr_r_plot<-round(corr_r_plot^2*100,digits=1)
  corr_r<-df.corr_coeff.r[1,2]

  if(corr_r_plot == 100) {analysis<-"perfect correlation"}
  if(corr_r_plot < 100) {analysis<-"very strong correlation"}
  if(corr_r_plot <= 64) {analysis<-"strong correlation"}
  if(corr_r_plot <= 36) {analysis<-"average correlation"}
  if(corr_r_plot <= 16) {analysis<-"weak correlation"}
  if(corr_r_plot <= 4) {analysis<-"very weak correlation"}
  if(corr_r_plot == 0) {analysis<-"no correlation"}

  if(corr_P_plot <= 0.05) {p_analysis<-"significant"}
  if(corr_P_plot > 0.05) {p_analysis<-"insignificant"}

  if(corr_r <0){direction<-"negative"}
  if(corr_r >0){direction<-"positive"}

  r<-round(corr_r,digits=2)
  mtext(expression(r^2), line=0.5,adj=0)
  mtext(paste("    = ",corr_r_plot,"% , ", "r = ",r,", ",direction, analysis,", ",p_analysis), side=3, line=0.5, adj=0)

  #dev.print(png,file="//laboratory data/Trendanalysis_R/test01.png",width=861,height=553,units="px",pointsize=8)
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO! Please create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `png` inside your loop and use `paste0` to create filenames. I have reworked your code to make it reproducible.

```
df <-matrix(runif(80),ncol=8)
colnames(df) <-letters[1:8]
for (i in 2:8){
titel<-paste("Trend analysis of", colnames(df)[i])
png(filename = paste0("c:/temp/test",i,".png"),width=861,height=553,units="px",pointsize=8)
plot(df[,i],ylab="Ammonia [mg/l]",main=titel,col.main="darkblue",pch=20,col="darkblue")
dev.off()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the help! I've integrated the commands into my loop like:

```
df<-matrix(runif(80),ncol=8)
colnames(df)<-letters[2:8]

for (i in 2:8){
  monitoring_well<-NH3[,i]
  titel<-paste("Trend analysis of", colnames(df)[,i])
  png(filename = paste0("//Fileserver/ocm-data/13/039_Cork CC/07_ Derryconnell/laboratory data/Trendanalysis_R/test",i,".png"),width=861,height=553,units="px",pointsize=8)
  plot(Date,df[,i],ylab="Ammonia [mg/l]",main=titel,col.main="darkblue",pch=20,col="darkblue")
}
```

But unfortunately, the error "Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log): 'x' and 'y' lengths differ" occurs. I tried different options, but I don't know, where the problem is.